# How to embed SQL Table to .Net Application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using SQL Server as database with VB.net to develop an application. Is there any way to embed the SQL db/table to the application so that client will not have to install SQL Server.

Comment: SqlLite would suffice, it's not a DBMS rather file system. Which in turns means the end client doesn't need anything. Also you can't embed SQL into the application as they would need the whole server for this...

Comment: Does it mean that the uses should have the same tables as i had at development time.

Comment: Yes they would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think recent versions of SQL Server have a feature called 'LocalDB' which might fit your needs : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx